# Get the value of public variable of one class from another class in C#

Tags: c#

I have a C# application which has logic some similar as below:

```
public ClassA {
    public string myID { get; set; }

    public void SetID(string jobID)
    {
        myID = jobID;    
    }

    public void SomeMethod(){
        ClassB b = new ClassB();
        LogMessage("Execution starts here");
        b.FetchData();
        LogMessage("Further execution");

    }
    public void LogMessage (string message){

        //some logic to write message into a text file with the following message :

        // "Id : " + myID + " --> " + message
    // next line (enter)
    }
}

public class ClassB(){

    public void FetchData(){
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        a.LogMessage("Fetch data starts");
        //some logic to fetch data
        a.LogMessage("Fetch data ends");
    }

}
```

The text file looks like this after this gets executed if id value is say "ABC":

```
Id : ABC --> Execution starts here
Id : (null) --> Fetch data starts
Id : (null) --> Fetch data ends
Id : ABC --> Further execution
```

The problem here I'm facing is the id is not getting printed even though it a public variable. When the execution goes into another class, `myId` variable becomes null. Also for some reasons I cannot pass `myId` variable as a parameter to `LogMessage()`.

What is a simple way to get myId value always without making it null from all methods? The above code is just the sample of what I have in my application. This similar logging is done in so many methods. This would be done in `LogMessage()`.

Comment: `myJobID = jobID; ` is that a typo? The member variable is named `myID`.

Comment: Is there any method named `LogMessage` Inside Class `ClassB` ?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I'm extremely sorry, it is a typo. I have rectified it now.

Comment: @user2932057 No, the method is in only ClassA

Comment: Your code is a bit confused. In `SomeMethod` in class A you are calling `FetchData` but that doesn't have a method by this name. Also what does the `LogMessage` method in Class B look like? That is the method that is apparently not doing what you expect but you aren't showing what it does or how you are trying to get the id from it. Or if as you've now indicated it is the one in class A you haven't indicated how you are calling it.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve]. There's a lot missing here.

Comment: Now you made it worse. ClassA depends on ClassB and ClassB depends on ClassA ... extract Logging into a Logger class (which may even implement an ILogger interface). Then inject an instance of that into both ClassA and ClassB.

Comment: @Fildor, I know :( can you tell me the best possible way of doing this?

Comment: It is impossible to tell you, why Id is null, without looking at actual implementation. You have not set the property 'myID ' after initializing instance of ClassA in FetchData Function. I recommend method overloading for LogMessage. You should not need SetID method, unless your myID is a private property.

Comment: @HiteshGaur It _is_ possible to tell and it is quite obvious: The ClassA instance created in ClassB is not the same as the instance of ClassA that created the instance of ClassB.

Comment: @Fildor, I typed in that line before, poster corrected his code for ClassB, because originally posted code was not going to compile, and it was confusing.

Comment: @HiteshGaur Ah, it was before edit, I see.

Comment: @CrazyCoder make both `myID` property and LogMessage method in `ClassA` as Static. Also, in ClassB - No need to create an instance everytime. Just call `ClassA.LogMessage`

Comment: @user2932057 No, don't do that. Logging is none of either's business.

Comment: @Fildor Then create a seperate class For logging messages seperately. That approach will be fine ?

Comment: @user2932057 Much cleaner, yes. In fact, I'd recommend to not invent the wheel again and use some Logging-Framework like NLog, log4net, Serilog ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LE: I see you corrected the variable typo and I see now the problem.

Inside ClassB you instantiate ClassA again which containts LogMessage but you don't call SetID (so myID is null).

LE2: I wouldn't have the log method inside any of these classes as the S from [SOLID](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design) principles state (a class needs to have a single responsibility). One approach you can take is to create a static class that takes care of the logging logic:

```
public static class Logger
{
    private static string myID;

    public static SetMyId(string id)
    {
        myID = id;
    }

    public static void Log(string message)
    {
        //print myID _+ message
    }
}
```

A static variable would preserve your ID for as long as the application is alive. Of course there are patterns out there exactly for this, so depending on your context it may be good to explore different other options depending on your needs (an [example](https://gist.github.com/heiswayi/69ef5413c0f28b3a58d964447c275058) I found at a simple google search) and also libraries that do the logging for you (some examples [here](https://www.loggly.com/blog/benchmarking-5-popular-net-logging-libraries/))

Comment: This answer has been invalidated by a correction to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Class variables, also called fields, exist per class instance (I am not talking about static fields here). I.e., each object has its own set of field values.

In `ClassB`, you create a new object with `ClassA a = new ClassA();`. This is not the same object whose `SomeMethod` you called.

You can pass a `ClassA` object to `ClassB` through constructor injection. Change `ClassB` to

```
public class ClassB()
{
    private readonly ClassA _a;

    // Constructor. You call it with `new ClassB(classAObject)`.
    public ClassB(ClassA a)
    {
        _a = a;
    }

    public void FetchData(){
        _a.LogMessage("Fetch data starts");
        // Fetching data here...
        _a.LogMessage("Fetch data ends");
    }
}
```

In `ClassA` change `SomeMethod` to

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    myID = "ABC";

    // Pass a reference to the current object (this).
    ClassB b = new ClassB(this);

    LogMessage("Execution starts here");
    b.FetchData();
    LogMessage("Further execution");
}
```

Also, there is no point in making a method `SetID`, as the `myID` property already has a public setter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add string to the Log message as you'll be passing in a variable called message which should be a string?

```
public void LogMessage (string message){

        //some logic to write message into a text file with the following message :

        // "Id : " + myID + " --> " + message
    // next line (enter)
    }
```

In class B there's no reference pointer to the instance of class a that you made. So I'm not sure how your even calling the method.

Add

```
public class ClassB(){

    ClassA NewMessage = new ClassA();

    public void FetchData(){

        NewMessage.LogMessage("Fetch data starts");
        //some logic to fetch data
        NewMessage.LogMessage("Fetch data ends");
    }

}
```

Comment: Tight coupling is not the best of ideas. Logging is not the responsibility of those classes. There should be a logger class, of which an instance is either injected or created.

Comment: So in this guys scenario, he should decouple the logmessage method away from class a and and move it into a logger class? Then initiate class B outside the SomeMethod() in class a?

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a starter on how to decouple a bit: "Quick and quite dirty":

```
public class Logger {
    public void LogMessage (string message, string myID){

        //some logic to write message into a text file with the following message :

        // "Id : " + myID + " --> " + message
    // next line (enter)
    }
}

public ClassA {
    private Logger logger = new Logger();

    public string myID { get; set; }

    // SetID is actually not necessary: just use classAInstance.myID = jobID; in the client of ClassA.
    // But I'd recommend making the Property Readonly and set it through CTOR if possible.


    public void SomeMethod(){
        ClassB b = new ClassB();
        logger.LogMessage("Execution starts here", myID);
        b.FetchData(logger, myID);
        logger.LogMessage("Further execution", myID);

    }

}

public class ClassB(){

    public void FetchData( Logger logger, string myID){

        logger.LogMessage("Fetch data starts", myID);
        //some logic to fetch data
        logger.LogMessage("Fetch data ends", myID);
    }
}
```

Could be further improved by:

- using an interface for Logger
- using a Logging Framework
- using Dependency Injection
- decouple ClassB from ClassA by using interfaces and DI.
- ...