# Declare log4net variables globally and use them across all class files

Tags: c#, log4net

I have a class library written in C#. In this library we have used log4net to do the logging. The class library has 2-3 class files. This class library is being used by a Windows service also written in C#.

Now the log4net has been implemented in the following manner:

1. I have added reference from nuget for `log4net`.
2. In each class file , added this on top:

   ```
    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
   ```
3. Wanted some extra details to be printed along with the default values, so added some parameters in log4net.config file as below:

   ```
    <parameterName value="@Parameter1"/>
    <parameterName value="@Parameter2"/>
   ```

and in layout pattern:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
     <conversionPattern value="%date{dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %level  :: Parameter1 = %property{Parameter1} :: Parameter2 = %property{Parameter2}:: %logger : %message%newline"   />
</layout>
```

And added this line in every method in `ClassA`, where logging is being done:

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["Parameter1"] = parameter1;
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["Parameter2"] = parameter2;
```

Now the problem I'm facing here is, say I have 2 class files in my class library named `Class1` and `Class2`. And `parameter1` and `parameter2` are public variables in `ClassA`. As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53066140/8930751), I'm not able to access `paramter1` and `parameter2` in `ClassB`. So when the logs of `classB` methods are printed, `parameter1` and `parameter2` are always null.

So is there a way I can set parameters globally once and whenever the logs are printed it uses the same variables.

My code is similar to below:

```
public ClassA {
    public string parameter1 { get; set; } = "ABC"
    public string parameter2 { get; set; } = "XYZ"
    
    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    public void SomeMethod(){
        log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["Parameter1"] = parameter1;
        log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["Parameter2"] = parameter2;
        ClassB b = new ClassB();
        log.info("In Some Method");
        b.AnotherMethod();
        LogMessage("After AnotherMethod");  
    }   
}

public class ClassB(){
    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    public void AnotherMethod(){        
        log.info("Inside AnotherMethod");       
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
30/10/18 21:57:11 [5] INFO  :: Parameter1 = 'ABC' :: Parameter2 = 'XYZ' :: ClassA : In Some Method
30/10/18 21:57:11 [5] INFO  :: Parameter1 = 'ABC' :: Parameter2 = 'XYZ' :: ClassB : Inside AnotherMethod
30/10/18 21:57:11 [5] INFO  :: Parameter1 = 'ABC' :: Parameter2 = 'XYZ' :: ClassA : After AnotherMethod
```

Actual output:

```
30/10/18 21:57:11 [5] INFO  :: Parameter1 = 'ABC' :: Parameter2 = 'XYZ' :: ClassA : In Some Method
30/10/18 21:57:11 [5] INFO  :: Parameter1 = (null) :: Parameter2 = (null) :: ClassB : Inside AnotherMethod
30/10/18 21:57:11 [5] INFO  :: Parameter1 = 'ABC' :: Parameter2 = 'XYZ' :: ClassA : After AnotherMethod
```

How can I make parameter 1 and 2 to print every time or declare it globally? So once I set, it has to be used by all the log4net messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line in your code:

```
log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

You end up with 2 different loggers and so the values you set for the logger in `ClassA` is not the same as the logger in `ClassB`.  Try changing those two lines to something like:

```
log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("MyLogger");
```

And it should work.

If you take a read through the documentation you will see that when you call [this](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/M_log4net_LogManager_GetLogger_5.htm) method that uses the type name to load the logger "The full name of type will be used as the name of the logger to retrieve."  Since you have two different types in your code you end up with two different loggers.  You need to either use a common name or a common type to get the same logger instance.

Your other option would be to set the value on the settings file, but I am guessing that won't work for you as they are probably values that you need to set at run time.

Comment: hey this worked for me, The values are retained for ClassB as well. But earlier , in my logs , it used to print ClassA and ClassB. Now it prints MyLogger. Is there anyway I can print ClassA and ClassB instead of MyLogger?

Comment: @CrazyCoder - Sorry, missed that you are also printing out the logger name. I don't think you can have it both ways, but would have to look through all the format arguments to see if you can stuff the class name in automagically. The issue is if you give a different logger name then it is a different logger.

Comment: I guess , I will have to add extra parameter for class name along with parameter1 and parameter2

Comment: @CrazyCoder - There is a pattern layout specifier for `type`, but the documentation warns about it being slow (and I would expect it to be so, as I would assume under the hood it is using reflection) - https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html

Comment: @CrazyCoder i think %stacktrace is what you are searching. At least it does not have the warning about "being slow".

Answer (score 2):

If you set properties in `log4net.GlobalContext`, they should be available to all loggers.  I'm not sure where or why you've added `parameterName` elements to your log4net.config file, but you shouldn't need them.

Typically you would set `log4net.GlobalContext` properties once at application startup.  If you want properties only for the duration of a method, you could consider using `log4Net.ThreadContext`.

[This dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bMWCan) is similar to your code and gives the result you say you want.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I'm using writing this in a class library which doesn't have any main as you have mentioned in the fiddler. Where do you think I should declare it globally?

Comment: It just needs to be declared globally before the first time you attempt to log.  Where exactly would depend on your application / library.  For example, you could have a  helper class that ensures the globalcontext properties are set, and call it from each one of your classes that logs.  Or a wrapper class for log4net that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could read and write to the settings file if you need to keep track of the these parameters across your library. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx